# Oracle columns update not happpening

Tags: sql, oracle, c#-4.0

I am trying to update a few columns in a Oracle table from my C# code.

Here is my method:

```
private static bool UpdateOracleTable(OracleTable table, string whereClause, List<int> entIDs)
    {
        try
        {
            var tableName = table.ToString();

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_oracleConnection))
            {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (var id in entIDs)
                {
                    whereClause = String.Format(whereClause, id);
                    var query = Resources.UpdateOracle;
                    query = String.Format(query, tableName, "20", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), whereClause);

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Debug(LogType.Error, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Query:

```
UPDATE 
{0}
SET
SYNC_STATUS = '{1}'
,SYNC_DATE = TO_DATE('{2}', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
{3}
```

And the where clause will look something like: 
    WHERE ID = {0}

This method updates about 10 records, and the rest stays null.  This mehod does return true, and I have debugged, no exception is thrown.

Why does it not update all records?

Comment: can you get exact text of command from `query`?

Comment: Sure, looking at the debugger, this is what is looks like:UPDATE \r\n\tXXTBPR_ORGANIZATIONS\r\nSET\r\n\tSYNC_STATUS = '20'\r\n\t,SYNC_DATE = TO_DATE('2014-09-12', 'yyyy/mm/dd')\r\nWHERE PROD_ORG_ID = 12
Cleaner version: UPDATE tXXTBPR_ORGANIZATIONS SET SYNC_STATUS = '20' ,SYNC_DATE = TO_DATE('2014-09-12', 'yyyy/mm/dd') WHERE PROD_ORG_ID = 12

Comment: can you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tXXTBPR_ORGANIZATIONS WHERE PROD_ORG_ID = 12`. Also how do you know that records are not updated??

Comment: Yes I can, I have checked and checked now, this is one of the few that is successfull, the others just fail.  I also checked a few that fails now, and when I run the count, it returns 0, so those are not updated, however, they do exist.  I am using SQL Developer

Comment: How do you know that they exist? it sounds strange considering that count is zero.

Comment: I meant to say it returned 1, so the record did exist.  Please see my solution to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but might help debug the problem.

Instead of the like:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

put in this:

```
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Put a break on the `Console.WriteLine("")` and run it. The debugger will stop if no rows were updated. You can then check the query, and whether or not that ID actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the WHERE clause.  Since it contains a place holder {0}, after I I formatted the WHERE clause, the ID always stayed to the value it was formatted with first.

This is what my new method looks like.

```
private static bool UpdateOracleTable(OracleTable table, string whereClause, List<int> entIDs)
    {
        try
        {
            var tableName = table.ToString();

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_oracleConnection))
            {
                conn.Open();

                foreach (var id in entIDs)
                {
                    string originalWhere = whereClause;
                    originalWhere = String.Format(originalWhere, id);
                    var query = Resources.UpdateOracle;
                    query = String.Format(query, tableName, "20", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), originalWhere);

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        bool success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Debug(LogType.Error, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As can be seen, I added a variable 'originalWhere', that gets formatted, but most importantly, is being set to original WHERE clause parameter passed, so that it will always contain the place holder.